# Como hacer que mi div tenga altura automática - CSS

Tags: css, css3, div

básicamente, mi problema está en que no sé como poner a mi div la altura automática (con CSS) para que así pueda hacer scroll dentro del div y no fuera. Cualquier duda sobre mi pregunta la puedo aclarar. Gracias.

Comment: Y si a tu div le adicionas una clase. y esta clase tiene el siguiente contenido *{height: 100px;overflow: scroll;}**.

Comment: ¿A que te refieres con _hacer scroll dentro del div y no fuera_?

Comment: Los `div` tienen altura automática dependiendo de su contenido. Por los comentarios y la respuesta aceptada, parece que lo que quieres es que el `div` tenga altura fija y muestre scroll si necesario

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo como podía quedar según tengo entendido tu pregunta:

```css
.scroll {
  height:250px; max-height:250px;
  width:400px;
  overflow-y:auto;
  overflow-x:hidden;
  }
```

```html
<div class="scroll">

     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras ullamcorper posuere interdum. Morbi id finibus mi. Sed euismod congue semper. Aliquam accumsan malesuada dapibus. Nullam vitae magna a ante eleifend laoreet nec sit amet sapien. Vestibulum non consequat nisi. Etiam lectus magna, egestas nec metus eget, placerat ultricies est. Cras vel metus nulla. Nam nec nunc nec justo iaculis tempus vel vel sem. Aliquam a massa maximus, aliquam dui nec, hendrerit mauris.<br />
<br />
Phasellus non vestibulum lacus. Sed in odio arcu. Vestibulum quis dui consequat, viverra lectus eleifend, posuere nunc. Curabitur facilisis, est non tristique sagittis, lectus massa congue sem, vitae dapibus quam turpis ut ligula. Praesent fringilla et nisi in imperdiet. Morbi ligula erat, ullamcorper tempor odio nec, dignissim ullamcorper lectus. In venenatis lectus sit amet mi mattis, non cursus justo pretium. Morbi rhoncus ante a felis ultrices tempus. Nulla ut ante et neque feugiat elementum. Aenean pharetra aliquam mi quis condimentum. Nunc scelerisque in enim sit amet porta. Donec vel dolor tincidunt, lobortis enim ut, viverra neque. Nulla fermentum sagittis molestie.<br />
<br />
Maecenas a malesuada odio. Maecenas ac tincidunt felis. Vivamus finibus orci tortor. Nunc fringilla odio id libero fringilla, in blandit libero pulvinar. Pellentesque a dictum dolor. Donec volutpat id nisi eget rhoncus. Quisque sollicitudin mauris eget felis scelerisque tempus. Pellentesque ornare odio mauris, vitae vulputate nisi interdum sagittis. Fusce eu pellentesque sem, non aliquet elit. Donec lacinia facilisis mollis. <br />

 </div>
```